# Wifi adapter found, but disconnected during boot due to link not ready

Tags: raspbian, usb, boot, wifi, pi-2

I recently bought a RPi2 and am currently in the process of installing it, but I can't get [my Wifi dongle](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessoires/realtek-8188cus-draadloze-nano-adapter-150mbps) (link in Dutch) working, even though it is supposed to be working "out of the box" and there should be "no need to install extra drivers"... uh-huh... I know there are quite a lot of "I have a WiFi problem"-posts but even after a lot of searching I still can't figure it out so I hope somebody can help me or point me in the right direction.

As to my setup, I did a fresh install of Raspbian and am currently running it with an ethernet cable which enables it to share an internet connection through my laptop (and connect from it to the Pi with SSH), I also have a mouse and monitor (HDMI) connected to try running it without the ethernet/laptop (installed virtual keyboard). The Pi is powered by a 5.2V/2A power adapter.

After the Wifi adapter wasn't picked up on the initial/clean install I updated the Pi with **apt-get update/upgrade** and **rpi-update**. As far as I can tell the Pi sees my adapter during bootup, but rejects it at the same time? Drivers seem to be present (8192cu I believe) and up-to-date as well (even tried updating them but got the message "firmware-realtek is already the newest version"). Below are some stats:

**uname -a**

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.13-v7+ #826 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:19:03 GMT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**lsusb** (notice the adapter not showing up here)

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsmod** (driver seems to be present?)

```
Module                  Size  Used by
8192cu                528485  0
cfg80211              419759  0
rfkill                 16659  1 cfg80211
evdev                  10226  2
bcm2835_gpiomem         3023  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         2966  0
uio                     8228  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                 6040  0
snd_bcm2835            19739  3
snd_pcm                74833  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              18164  1 snd_pcm
snd                    52116  9 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
fuse                   81721  3
ipv6                  341380  36
```

After running **sudo dmesg -C**, replugging the adapter and typing **dmesg** I got:

```
[ 3809.142112] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 18 using dwc_otg
[ 3809.243844] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8176
[ 3809.243872] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3809.243890] usb 1-1.5: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[ 3809.243907] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 3809.243923] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[ 3810.022433] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 3810.190677] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ 3810.191263] rtw_cmd_thread: DriverStopped(0) SurpriseRemoved(1) break at line 482
```

I guess it has something to do with the "link" (whatever that may be) not being ready, but I don't know what it means or how to solve it. Furthermore, **ifconfig** only shows *eth0* and *lo* (so NO *wlan0*), and **sudo iwlist wlan0 scan** results in "wlan0 Interface doesn't support scanning.". So far, I haven't touched the "/etc/network/interfaces". I also tried putting the adapter in all the different USB-slots and even in an externally powered USB hub but all to no avail. I have no idea what else I can do/try and if it wasn't for the mention in the dmesg results I would conclude the adapter is broken (but it is newly bought and does show up so I guess it's a software thingy somewhere).

Any help appreciated!  :)

PS. If any extra information is needed let me know and I will post it!

*Edit 25/11* - Added a bit of extra info about the way my Pi is connected, and the drivers used for tying it on my laptop (MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan): first tried the drivers from the [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=274&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2747) site since the provided minicd with drivers doesn't go into my Mac. When those didn't seem to work I tried [these](http://www.hackintoshosx.com/files/file/4587-all-in-one-kext-for-realtek-wireless-usb-adapters-el-capitan-ready/) but those resulted in an error during install (next to a warning the thing could break my system). Neither enabled me to find an *USB WiFi* option in the *network* tab of the *system preferences* panel. I'm wondering though, if the adapter would be defect why does it show up in the Pi's dmesg-log and my Mac's *System Report*?

Comment: If `lsusb` does not list the dongle, then it doesn't matter what other files you list. It is unclear from your question how the Pi is connected or what you expect the WiFi to do. You have made life difficult for yourself by running `rpi-update`. I suggest you make a clean image, and DON'T install unproven bleeding edge software.

Comment: `ifconfig` only shows interfaces that are in an "up" state (not the same as connected, but a prerequisite). `ifconfig -a` or `ip link` will show everything regardless.  Milliways is right that not having something listed by `lsusb` is a fatal sign...

Comment: ...but I'll disagree about the significance of `rpi-update` -- all it does is update the kernel and pi firmware.  Today's "clean image" contains yesterday's "rpi-update" stuff, and the difference is not because they are waiting for the "bleeding edge" to become "proven", but because the images are only released every so often.  It could coincidentally make a difference here, but not very likely, and just as easily one way as the other.

Comment: If the you think the adapter is broken try it on another computer. You probably can complain to the supplier. Other wifi adapters should also work, see [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters)

Comment: @Milliways as mentioned the Pi is connected with a USB mouse, an ethernet cable (sharing my laptop wifi connection and enabling a ssh-connection), a monitor (HDMI cable) and also a 5.2V/2A adapter for power. As to what I expect the Wifi to do, well.. work? :) I understand your concern about the `rpi-update` but it wasn't working with the clean image either so I thought let's make sure everything is up-to-date.

Comment: @goldilocks `ifconfig -a` and `ip link` both only show _lo_ and _eth0_ as well, probably no surprise as the adapter doesn't show up in the `lsusb` list, which you and Milliways already stated was fatal

Comment: I think we get a lot of complaints about this chipset, possibly because they are very common, but also because there are driver issues on linux.  I have one in a TP-LINK adapter, and one thing I noticed a while ago was it got very warm when used with a pi and sometimes disconnected (whereas it did not on an x86_64 box also running linux). My recommendation with the pi and wifi adapters is, if possible, to buy one at a local store that will take it back within a few days (big retailers here are like that if you put the packaging back together and say it works, but not for your purposes).

Comment: Are you sure the `firmware-realtek` package is installed? If `aptitude search ~ifirmware-realtek` returns something, then it is installed. If not, then that is likely your problem. Things not showing up in `lsusb` is often caused by missing firmware.

Comment: @goldilocks you should **not** run `rpi-update` unless you're specifically instructed by the raspberry pi kernel developers or you actively want to develop things for/against the kernel. It has been discouraged for a while now. The difference between `rpi-update` and an update to `raspberrypi-bootloader` is that the latter has been tested for a while and considered 'stable' (enough). That package is updated more often then an image is released.
It likely doesn't make a difference for the problem at hand, but your statement is (still) wrong.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas I'm not a cargo cult member. If you can provide a reference for this besides yourself (and various forum posts which speculate using both `apt-get` and `rpi-update` could lead to a mismatch of firmware and kernel, which is a combination of **false and irrelevant**), I'd be happy to correct or delete my comment.

Comment: @goldilocks "mismatch of firmware and kernel" you won't hear me say that ... ever, because both `apt-get` and `rpi-update` will provide matching kernel/firmware. It's just that the `rpi-update` method can give you a new kernel/firmware which is literally minutes old depending on when you run it. I'm pretty sure I got the info about deprecation of `rpi-update` from XECDesign/ShiftPlusOne (=same person), but don't know whether he said so on the #raspbian IRC channel or the forums.
If I do find the reference, I'll post it.

Comment: @DiederikdeHaas Right, that would be the "false" side -- except it's "irrelevant", as there is no *matching* of or correspondence between these two things, other than that they reside on the same partition.  The firmware bootloader does not care about the nature of the kernel, the kernel never even knows about the bootloader.  Beware there's firmware which does/can come with the kernel (such as the stuff for this realtek chip) that has nothing to do with this and resides in `/lib/firmware` without any specific per kernel directory, because...

Comment: ...again there is no correspondence beyond the means of distribution.  WRT using or not using `rpi-config`, my opinion would be you might as well stick with `apt-get` but there is no real risk of harm in it.  **The kernel from `rpi-update` is not at all some latest-minute development version.**  Whoever told you it is was just blathering. It's [from here](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware); notice that's v. 4.1.13, matching [the current github default](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux), well behind the latest available source (4.4).

Comment: It was also compiled 22 days ago, which your average raspbian update is probably not much less frequent. My original point was this would at best be a fluke factor here, and the fluke could be on either side -- presuming that the distro kernel is at all different, which quite possibly it isn't anyway.  I.e., they're probably the same most of the time.

Comment: I'm not going to continue discussing `rpi-update` as I've said earlier I don't think it's relevant for the problem at hand. 
I wanted to express support for Milliways' statement, but apparently couldn't do that by upvoting, thus added a comment myself to do so.

Comment: Well, it is relevant in so far as you are implicitly supporting Milliway's claim the OP has "made life difficult...by running rpi-update", which is a total red herring.  But I agree we've both made our point clear.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a process by the name ifplugd running on the wlan0? If not it might
indicate the adapter is not completely registered with the device.

As a start, you could try installing and connecting to the network through your laptop.

Comment: As far as I can tell (tried `ps` and `ps axg`) there is no such process. I tried installing it on my laptop but no success there either (not sure if that is because of my lack of experience with wifi dongles or the thing is broken). I'll edit the steps I did in my original post

Comment: If it is the only USB Wireless adapter and if there is no entry (wlan0?) under /sys/class/net/, then the OS does not see it which could be the reason as to why you are not able to configure it.